# Where is build.xml in android

Tags: android

I m making an app which shares its file from assets folder and I m sharing an xml file to other app it gives me this exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed
```

I got this [TUTORIAL](http://www.xinotes.net/notes/note/1294/) but at point number 7 it says that "ADD THIS SECTION TO THE END OF build.xml" so where can I get this build.xml??

And any way around to resolve this exception??

I m using MAC OS X

Answer (score 0):

Run android update **project -p** ..., where the ... is the path to the project. This will create or update the build.xml and related command-line build files. This assumes that your SDK's tools/ directory in your PATH; otherwise, you will need to fully-qualify the path to the android command.I hope it will helps you .

Answer (score 0):

Follow this Procedure To Use ***`build.xml`***

Go to your Android SDK installation, and open the file "`tools/ant/build.xml`", copy the complete "test" target and paste it in the "build.xml" of the test project, before the import of `build.xml`, so before the comment starting with "Import the actual build file". There is more information on how to customize targets in that comment.

If its Confusing Follow [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+an+Android+app+and+test+project) for Complete Ant....

Hope You understand..

Comment: I still didn't get it that what is this "test" target?